# NFS Ubuntu Server 17.10 client does not see mounted volume

Tags: server, 17.10, nfs

I have Ubuntu Server 17.10 with many features also NFS Server is running at home. Also I have 1Tb mounted volume on point /home/myaccount/hdd. All is OK but clients do not see mounted volume.
/etc/exports is:
/home/myaccount 192.168.1.0/24(rw,insecure,nohide,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_subtree_check).
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I need to change owner of my hdd:
chown -hR nobody:nogroup /home/myaccount/hdd
then I need to edit /etc/exports:
vim /etc/exports
/home/myaccount 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,all_squash,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)
after that all is working!
May be some options is not important...